# how to avoid mounting directories with overcomplicated paths?

Tags: shell, mount, path, raspbian

Background:

I am accessing a remote directory like this:

```
smb://serv.erNa.me/storage/directory/
```

Accessing it, is not an issue. Through the file manager I copy paste the path, press Enter, insert user and password and, eventually, I can see the content of the directory. That is fine, if I want to browse its content.

But, if I need to access this directory through the shell (suppose to Open a Terminal Here, from the file manager) to launch some scripts, I fall into an overcomplicated series of subdirectories and my path looks like this:

```
/run/user/1000/gvfs/smb-share:server=serv.erNa.me,share=storage/directory
```

which is kind of impossible to manage, if I have to perform some operations over filenames and paths (which is exactly what I need to to).

A few experiments I performed:

1. I noticed that if I have a virtualbox installed, that has a shared directory pointing to the directory of interest:

   ```
   smb://serv.erNa.me/storage/directory/
   ```

   in the virtualised Ubuntu, the mount point is nice and clean:

   ```
   /media/storage/directory
   ```

   and I can simply run the scripts and everything goes fine. **But** I need to run the scripts without the need of a virtualbox since it makes everything slow.
2. I also tried:

   ```
   mkdir /media/short/
   mount -t cifs -o rw,guest,vers=1.0,noperm,sec=none smb://serv.erNa.me/storage/directory/ /media/short/
   ```

   but that gives an error:

   ```
   mounting cifs URL not implemented yet. Attempt to mount smb://serv.erNa.me/storage/directory/
   ```

The question:

Why is that? How can virtualbox use a very clean and readable mounting point while, if I want to access the same directory from my system I need to go through the horrible path shown above?

Is there a way I can set something more user-friendly?

Comment: @Fabby: no I haven't but now that I did it returns an error message:
`mount.cifs: bad UNC (///serv.erNa.me/storage/directory/)`.

Comment: I also tried `mount -t cifs -o rw,guest,vers=1.0,noperm,sec=none smb://serv.erNa.me/storage/directory/ /media/short/` but it gives another error like: 
`mounting cifs URL not implemented yet. Attempt to mount smb://serv.erNa.me/storage/directory/`

Comment: My apologies: no further bright ideas...  All my comments deleted. See my [edits](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/517992/revisions). You can delete all the above comments now.

Comment: Don't include `smb:` in the remote path you pass to `mount`. Try `mount -t cifs -o rw,guest,vers=1.0,noperm,sec=none //serv.erNa.me/storage/directory/ /media/short/`. You can read about this with `man mount` and `man mount.cifs`.

Comment: @roaima and fabby thanks to both of you. I'll post the actual answer but mount cifs is the way to go!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this answer: https://askubuntu.com/questions/101029/how-do-i-mount-a-cifs-share

which exactly achieve what I needed, I simply didn't know about **mount.cifs**.

In the end, this is what I did:

```
$ sudo apt install cifs-utils
$ mkdir /media/short/
$ sudo mount -t cifs -o username=yourUserName //serv.er.name/storage/ /media/short/
```